# What is the proper structure for accessing a database on mobile apps?

Tags: android, sql, networking, mobile

I'm a complete beginner with mobile development. A friend of mine approached me with a project idea, asking me if it was possible to do it. The way I see it, it is a mobile app that needs to read and write data on a database in order to write inspection reports on the job of various staff members.

I told that friend that I would check how mobile development works first and would try to create a prototype to present. I've asked and Android is the main platform that is desired, so I've tried working with Android Studio and it is pretty straight forward up to now.

So, now I'm wondering what is the proper way to sync mobile apps with the database. Last time I worked with a database in a project we had multiple clients connecting to a server to play some small game together and the server would access the database and send the data back to the client through the network connection. So, I was wondering if a mobile app was supposed to use this communication structure or would simply talk directly to the database instead of a server.

The structure I have in mind:

[image: Mobile app communication structure with the database]

Is this an acceptable structure? Or am I thinking of this the wrong way?

Comment: Yes, the good old client-server model is acceptable.

Comment: @RamithDR Awesome, thanks!